# How can I create a logitnormal variable in pymc

Tags: pymc

I would like to use a latent variable which is LogitNormal Distributed in pymc. Can I do this in pymc ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution.

I dont see a standard class like I see for the Dirichlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is for pymc3)

You can either create a new distribution quite easily: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/distributions/continuous.py#L132

Or just logit-transform a normal

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model():
    pm.Deterministic('logit normal', pm.transforms.inverse_logit(pm.Normal('orig normal', 0, 1)))
    trace = pm.sample(5000)

pm.traceplot(trace)
```

[image]